# What is the most elegant way of describing textually a table

Tags: tablelayout, tabular

Here is the situation. I am working in epidemiological research and describing tables is something we have to do on a day-to-day basis. Content editing tools and their associated language all offers ways to describe a table. Here are a few example :

**Latex**

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9    
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Markdown**

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

Some of these are clearer than others, but all of them start to look absolutely horrific once one try to modify their formating to something other than the most basic example.

My question is the following :

> Given that this is one of the most fundamental tasks of text editing, what is the most elegant way/language we know to represent textually a non-trivial table and its content?

Comment: I'd say "HTML" because the syntax is unambiguous to the computer, and largely speaking, human-readable.  Markdown is *very* human-readable, but not unambiguous (why 6 hyphens instead of 12?  Does it matter to the computer?) whereas Latex is the opposite: as a human, I have no idea WTF that table looks like.  Is it "the **most** elegant?"  No idea.